# Property not returning and no error with datetime

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have the following model defined in Django:

```
class MasterBudget(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    expiry_date = models.DateField()

    @property
    def days_to_expiry(self):
        todays_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        datetime.timedelta(7)
        days_until = (self.expiry_date - todays_date).days
        return days_until
```

With the property returning days until expiry.

In my view, I get no value coming through when I reference:

```
{{budget.days_to_expiry}}
```

and no error on the console that something has gone wrong.

I know my naming is correct as if I do the following:

```
@property
def days_to_expiry(self):
    return 1
    todays_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    datetime.timedelta(7)
    days_until = (self.expiry_date - todays_date).days
```

I see the '1' in the view.

Any idea whats causing this?

Comment: Note that the call to `datetime.timedelta(7)` in both snippets has *absolutely no effect at all*.

Comment: Thanks for the headsup. I thought it allowed the two to be compared as integers (days without time). Removed it but still no luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're only using a [`DateField()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#datefield):

> A date, represented in Python by a `datetime.date` instance

Maybe try doing something like this:

```
class MasterBudget(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    expiry_date = models.DateField()

    @property
    def days_to_expiry(self):
        todays_date = datetime.date.today()
        return (self.expiry_date - todays_date).days
```

It will return the number of days between the `expiry_date` and today.

Is that what you were hoping to accomplish?

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to accomplish! Thanks, works like a charm

Comment: @NickP Glad it helped you! Good luck!